# iOS GameCenter Matchmaker not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, game-center

I’m trying to make a custom matchmakingview using a matchmaker. The code below is used to find a match.

When i run this on two different devices with different Game Center accounts, both will get a match but none will connect to the match. They will just get stuck in the while loop in infinity and never get out. Have i missed something, do you need to call something to actually connect to the match?

```
- (void) findMatch{
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;
request.playersToInvite = nil;
NSLog(@"Start searching!");

[matchmaker findMatchForRequest:request
               withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error) {
         // Print the error
         NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
     }
     else if (match != nil)
     {
         curMatch = match;
         curMatch.delegate = self;


         NSLog(@"Expected: %i", match.expectedPlayerCount);

         while (match.expectedPlayerCount != 0){
             NSLog(@"PLayers: %i", curMatch.playerIDs.count);
         }
         NSLog(@"Start match!");
     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using a while loop to wait for expectedPlayerCount to reach 0, instead implement the GKMatchDelegate method:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state {
    if (!self.matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0) {
        self.matchStarted = YES;
        //Now you should start your match.
    }
}
```